# track URL click on email with GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I was wondering how can we track a click on a link sent via email using Google Tag Manager.

I mean, the user gets an email that contains an URL to our website, we would like to know if the user clicks on that link.

Is it possible to do it all just using the GTM console or do we have to add some extra code to fire up the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be pedantic, you cannot track the "click" on the link since the mail itself does not contain tracking code or GTM code.

However you can append a parameter to the link (if you are using Google Analytics you should tag all of your links with [campaign parameters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en&ref_topic=1032998#parameters) in any case). Then you can check within GTM (e.g. via a url type variable with component type set to query string) if the parameter is present and then fire your tags accordingly.

Comment: no worries, yeah I was thinking on doing that, the email would have the link: http://testurl.com/page/content?source=email and the GTM tag will fire when source=email is present. Just was wondering if there is a different approach

Comment: You could send email users through a redirect page where the hit is recorded before they are sent to their destination (that's how tracking in most newsletter software works). But I think having the parameter is easier. But code within emails will in most cases not work.

Comment: Hey but you cant' add javascript code on an email this will no pass the Spam filter and the security policy.

Comment: @Eduardo there's no reason to use GTM to fire a custom tag when the query string equals or contains some arbitrary parameter (that you made up)...it'll cause lots of problems (like fragmenting your pageviews). Use this form: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/ It will build a valid URL that has standard GA campaign tracking parameters, which as Eike noted, Google innately understands and process properly.